# Javascript functional programming / Passing parameters

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I started experimenting with functional programming lately and I'm trying to convert an old module I have written using imperative programming.

Let's say I have two arrays of objects i.e

```
orders: [
  {
   idOrder: 1,
   amount: 100,
   customerId: 25,
  },
  {
   idOrder: 2,
   amount: 200,
   customerId: 20,
  }
]


customers: [
  {
   customerId: 20,
   name: "John Doe",
   orders: []
  },
  {
   customerId: 25,
   name: "Mary Jane",
   orders: []
  }
]
```

I want to push all the orders to their respective customer. Is there a clean way of doing it?

I have tried this , but obviously it doesn't work that way :

```
customers.orders = orders.filter((x) => {
  if (x.customerId === customerId) {
    customer.orders.push(x);
  }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: please add the code you have and what you have tried.

Comment: For Java see: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html

Comment: @donlys — But the question isn't about Java

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and get all customers first and then push the orders to the customers.

```js
var object = { orders: [{ idOrder: 1, amount: 100, customerId: 25 }, { idOrder: 2, amount: 200, customerId: 20 }], customers: [{ customerId: 20, name: "John Doe", orders: [] }, { customerId: 25, name: "Mary Jane", orders: [] }] },
    map = object.customers.reduce((m, a) => m.set(a.customerId, a), new Map);

object.orders.forEach(a => map.get(a.customerId).orders.push(a));

console.log(object.customers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

```
for (c of customers){
    c.orders.push(orders.filter( function(o){ return o.customerId === c.customerId} ));

}
```

Comment: this is going to push an array of orders into the customer.orders array.  Assuming customers have no orders you could do `c.orders = orders.filter(...`

Answer (score 0):

If you think of `customers` as your accumulator you can [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) `orders` with `customers` as your initial value.

NOTE: this does mutate `customers` if you do not want this as a side-effect you would have to **clone** `customers`. Also there is not error handling for customerId not found.

```js
var orders =  [{ idOrder: 1, amount: 100, customerId: 25 }, { idOrder: 2, amount: 200, customerId: 20}];
var customers =  [{ customerId: 20, name: "John Doe", orders: [] }, { customerId: 25, name: "Mary Jane", orders: [] } ];

var customers_orders = orders.reduce( 
               (accum, v) => 
                   { accum.find(
                            c => c.customerId == v.customerId).orders.push(v);
                     return accum; 
                   }, customers);

console.log(customers_orders);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function and pass it to reduce method and compose it with map

Just one things: once it's created, it may never change. You can user Object.assign and concat.

```
var customersWithOrders = customers.map(function(customer) {
  var relatedOrders = orders.filter(function(order) { return order.customerId === customer.customerId })
  return Object.assign(
    customer, 
    {
      orders: customer.orders.concat(relatedOrders)
    }
  )
})
```